# Multiple users accessing the same VM in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

In Microsoft Azure, how can I connect to a VM that someone else on my team has launched? I do not have the private key as of now - does it make sense to share that private key among the two of us? I am new to using Azure, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: FYI this belongs on SuperUser, not Stack Overflow - it's unrelated to programming. That said: not sure what you mean by "private key" - if it's a VM, then it has users created on the VM, right? You should be able to connect via a set of credentials configured on the VM.

Comment: Hello @KunalSinha, If You have AAD authentication  enabled for the VM and you can ask your IT admin to provide "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" or "Virtual Machine User Login" RBAC role to you and you can access the same VM after that using your AAD account. You can refer: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/azure-ad-authentication-to-windows-vms-in-azure-now-in-public/ba-p/827840